# Draw method of the UIView calls after the end of the for loop

Tags: ios, swift3, uiview, draw

I want to make set of circles. I have created a circle Class that extended from `UIView`. And this is my draw method.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    self.drawCircle()
}

func drawCircle()
{
    print("centerX-----\(RDcircleEnum.circleCenterX.getValues())")
    print("centerY-------\(RDcircleEnum.circleCenterY.getValues())")
    print("Radius--------\(RDcircleEnum.circleRadius.getValues())")
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.init(x: RDcircleEnum.circleCenterX.getValues(), y: RDcircleEnum.circleCenterY.getValues()), radius: CGFloat(RDcircleEnum.circleRadius.getValues()), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    self.layer.mask = shapeLayer

}
```

Then in my circleManager class I am doing like this

```
open func setupCirclestack(parentFrame:CGRect)->[Circle]
{
    var arrayCircles = Array<Any>()
    let arrayColor=[UIColor.yellow,UIColor.blue,UIColor.red]

    for i in 0...2//<CircleValues().numberOfCircles-1
    {
        let circle=self.getInnerCircle(currentFrame: parentFrame) as! Circle
        circle.backgroundColor=arrayColor[i]
        arrayCircles.append(circle)
        let cv=CircleValues.sharedInstance
        cv.radius=cv.radius-20
    }
    return arrayCircles as! [Circle]
}

func getInnerCircle(currentFrame:CGRect)->UIView
{
    print("New Radius------\(CircleValues.sharedInstance.radius)")
    let circle=Circle.init(frame: currentFrame)
    return circle
}
```

In the log I see like this

```
New Radius------Optional(187.0)
New Radius------Optional(167.0)
New Radius------Optional(147.0)

centerX-----207.0
centerY-------207.0
Radius--------127.0
centerX-----207.0
centerY-------207.0
Radius--------127.0
centerX-----207.0
centerY-------207.0
Radius--------127.0
```

the draw method calls only after whole iteration finished. So all the circles are having the same radius. How can I solve this? Please help me.

**UPDATE**

in Circle class

```
var innerCircleRadius:CGFloat = 187
```

in circleManager

```
for i in 0...2//<CircleValues().numberOfCircles-1
    {

      let circle=self.getInnerCircle(currentFrame: parentFrame) as! Circle
        circle.backgroundColor=arrayColor[i]
        arrayCircles.append(circle)
        circle.innerCircleRadius=circle.innerCircleRadius-20
        print("New Radius------\(circle.innerCircleRadius)")


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object should hold its own data - just put the circle's `radius` as a property of the `Circle` class itself, so that the draw method would be able to draw the circle properly regardless on when it is called.

In your update code, just change the circle manager to the following:

```
var currentCircleRadius = CGFloat(180)
for i in 0...2//<CircleValues().numberOfCircles-1
    {
        let circle=self.getInnerCircle(currentFrame: parentFrame) as! Circle
        circle.backgroundColor=arrayColor[i]
        arrayCircles.append(circle)
        circle.innerCircleRadius = currentCircleRadius
        currentCircleRadius = currentCircleRadius - 20
        print("New Radius------\(circle.innerCircleRadius)")
    }
```

Comment: I want to change the radius and create different circles.

Comment: each circle will have its own radius.. what is the problem? go and take a look at a object oriented programming..

Comment: No difference. the problem is it executes after all the iterations. So it takes the last assigned radius value. If I have a single circle it works. But when I run through a loop all the circles have same radius

Comment: of course, because in each circle you access the same variable as the radius. I told you to create a property in the circle class, so each circle can have its own radius, and in the loop just asign a proper value to that property.

Comment: can you see my updated part of the question. I have put  innercircleradius as a property. And in each iteration trying to reduce it by 20. But its still same

Comment: yes, because in each iteration you are using the default value of the `circle.innerCircleRadius` (which is 187) and then you subtract 20 from it, thus each circle will have radius 167. Use the code from my updated answer